# Vectorization of python numpy code is making it slower instead of faster

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, cross-correlation

I am trying to perform image correlation to find which frame out of a set of 20 frames (the set is stored in a 3D array, x) matches best with a given frame (stored as a 2D array, y). This step has to be performed 1000 times.

I tried to vectorize the code to make it run faster. But somehow the vectorization is making the code take twice as long. I am probably doing something wrong in the vectorization process which is making it slower.

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import time


def corr2(a,b):


    #Getting shapes and prealocating the auxillairy variables
    k = np.shape(a)

    #Calculating mean values
    AM=np.mean(a)
    BM=np.mean(b)  

    #calculate vectors
    c_vect = (a-AM)*(b-BM)
    d_vect = (a-AM)**2
    e_vect = (b-BM)**2

    #Formula itself
    r_out = np.sum(c_vect)/float(np.sqrt(np.sum(d_vect)*np.sum(e_vect)))

    return r_out


def ZZ_1X_v1_MCC(R,RefImage):

    from img_proccessing import corr2

    Cor = np.zeros(R.shape[2])
    for t in range(R.shape[2]):
        Cor[t]=corr2(RefImage,R[:,:,t]) #Correlation

    #report
    max_correlationvalue_intermediate = np.amax(Cor)
    max_correlatedframe_intermediate = np.argmax(Cor)

    max_correlatedframeandvalue = [max_correlatedframe_intermediate,max_correlationvalue_intermediate];

    return max_correlatedframeandvalue

def ZZ_1X_v1_MCC_vectorized(R,RefImage):


    R_shape = np.asarray(np.shape(R))
    R_flattened = R.swapaxes(0,2).reshape(R_shape[2],R_shape[0]*R_shape[1])
    AA = np.transpose(R_flattened)
    RefImageflattened = RefImage.transpose().ravel()

    #Calculating mean subtracted values
    AAM = AA - np.mean(AA,axis=0)
    BM = RefImageflattened - np.mean(RefImageflattened)

    #calculate vectors
    DD_vect = AAM**2
    E_vect = BM**2
    EE_vect = np.transpose(np.tile(np.transpose(E_vect),(R_shape[2],1)))
    CC_vect = AAM*np.transpose(np.tile(BM,(R_shape[2],1)))

    #Formula itself
    Cor = np.sum(CC_vect,axis=0)/np.sqrt((np.sum(DD_vect,axis=0)*np.sum(EE_vect,axis=0)).astype(float))

    #report
    max_correlationvalue_intermediate = np.amax(Cor)
    max_correlatedframe_intermediate = np.argmax(Cor)

    max_correlatedframeandvalue = [max_correlatedframe_intermediate,max_correlationvalue_intermediate];


    return max_correlatedframeandvalue   


x = np.arange(400000).reshape((20,200,100)).swapaxes(0,2) #3D array with 20 frames
y = np.transpose(np.arange(20000).reshape((200,100))) #2D array with 1 frame



# using for loop
tic = time.time()
for i in range(500):
    [a,b] = ZZ_1X_v1_MCC(x,y)

print(time.time() - tic)


# using vectorization
tic = time.time()
for i in range(500):
    [a,b] = ZZ_1X_v1_MCC_vectorized(x,y)
print(time.time() - tic)
```

Comment: Plez edit the indents

Comment: ZookZik_1X_v1_MaximumCorrelationCluster_please_cleanup_your_minimal_self_contained_sample_function_names

Comment: `import img_proccessing`? Are you sure? Is there anything else that isn't right in your example? Also, I suggest using `timeit` for timing stuff.

Comment: There's a considerable amount of back and forth transpositions going on in your vectorized code. For huge arrays, this can be very inefficient. If you can clearly specify in simple terms what you're trying to compute, we could probably come up with a more efficient solution.